# Adding a segue from a search results UITableView

Tags: iphone, xcode, swift

So I have a UITableView populated with questions. The cells of this table have a segue relationship to another view that contains the answer to the question. This segue has an identifier 'showAnswer'. Now I want to implement search functionality on the question table and I want each cell in the results to also segue to the answers view.

So in the question table controller have the code to add the search bar and its controller (this in Swift by the way but the logic is still the same):

```
    let resultsController = SearchResultsController()
    resultsController.questions = questions
    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: resultsController)

    let searchBar = searchController.searchBar
    searchBar.placeholder = "Enter a search term..."
    searchBar.sizeToFit()
    questionTable.tableHeaderView = searchBar
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = resultsController
```

Now in the SearchResultsController once a row has been selected I want to segue to the answers view. Here is what I got:

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
                performSegueWithIdentifier("showAnswer", sender: self)
            }
```

Now this crashes and I get the error that 'reciever SearchResultsController has no segue with identifier 'showAnswer'. This makes sense, but how do I fix this? Since I added the SearchResultsController programmatically there is nothing for me to ctrl+drag to on the storyboard to create a segue relationship between the SearchResultsController and the AnswersController. So what do I do?

Comment: I'm facing exactly the same problem - Have you found any solution to this? My setup is a little more complicated. My `UISearchController` is presented modally upon tapping a search button and it's installed in a master view controller of a `UISplitViewController`... Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect the segue from the holding view controller to the answers view and perform the segue from the holding view controller instead of from the search controller.

you should also send the appropriate data in the sender argument of the segue so the view controller you are navigating to can change according to the question that was chosen

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    YourViewController.performSegueWithIdentifier("showAnswer", sender: questions[indexPath.row])
        }
```